# SQL retrieving most recent record (dated) per ID?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT detailsID,`Topic 1 Scores`, MAX(Date) as "Date" 
FROM Information.scores 
WHERE `Topic 1 Scores` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY `detailsID`,`Topic 1 Scores`
```

Is printing;

```
detailsID, Topic 1 Scores, MAX(Date)

2 0 26/09/2017

2 45 26/09/2017

2 100 26/09/2017

3 30 25/09/2017

3 80 14/10/2017
```

Rather than actually selecting the most recent date per detailsID which would be:

2 100 26/09/2017

3 80 14/10/2017

I want to retrieve TOPIC 1 SCORES with the most recent score (excluding null) (sorted by date) for each detailsID, (there are only detailsID 2 and 3 here, therefore only two results should return)

[Solution 1 attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThmdI.png)

[Inner subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnY8g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT t1.detailsID, t1.`Topic 1 Scores`, t1.date
FROM scores as t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT detailsID, MAX(date) as "LatestDate" 
    FROM scores 
    WHERE `Topic 1 Scores` IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY `detailsID`
) AS t2 ON t1.detailsID = t2.detailsID AND t1.date = t2.LatestDate
```

- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a69dd8/1)

The subquery will give you the most recent date for each `detailsID` then in the outer query, there is a join with the original table to eliminate all the rows except those with the most recent date.

---

***Update:***

There are some rows with the same latest date, thats why you will have multiple rows with the same date and the same detailsID, to solve this you can add another aggregate for the score, so that you have only one row for each details id with the latest date and max score:

```
SELECT t1.detailsID, t1.`Topic 1 Scores`, t1.date
FROM scores as t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT detailsID, MAX(`Topic 1 Scores`) AS MaxScore, MAX(date) as "LatestDate" 
    FROM scores 
    WHERE `Topic 1 Scores` IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY `detailsID`
) AS t2  ON t1.detailsID = t2.detailsID 
        AND t1.date = t2.LatestDate
        AND t1.`Topic 1 Scores` = t2.MaxScore
```

- [updated demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67ede/4)

Results:

```
| detailsID | Topic 1 Scores |       date |
|-----------|----------------|------------|
|         2 |            100 | 2017-09-26 |
|         3 |             80 | 2017-10-14 |
```

Comment: If someone with a rep of 1 (now 21 - and counting :-) ) can get this right, how come so many contributors to this tag with reps in the thousands so often get it wrong?

Comment: @LottieT - My statement returns only distinct `detailsid` with the most recent score, in the results in your comment there are three rows with the same detailsID of 2, which is impossible to return it in this way. In the sqlfiddle demo, are the results returned correct? which are `2 2017-09-30` and `3 2017-10-14`??

Comment: @DorothyChen I have added a screenshot in the question to illustrate, hmm very strange

Comment: @LottieT No screenshots, thanks. Instead provide a fiddle, as per DC's example

Comment: @LottieT - Very strange, can you show me the results of the inner subquery only??

Comment: @DorothyChen i have posted screenshot of inner sub query only, it returns two results (one per ID) BUT not the most recent :(

Comment: @LottieT - The thing is that, there are multiple rows with the same latest row, so for those rows, which one you need to return? see this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67ede/3

Comment: I think my problem is the way I have saved the date. The date is in the 15/10/2017 rather than 2017-10-15 so when finding the most recent date it looks at the "15" to compare rather than the whole date. Do you know of a way to reformat all the dates into your format, without having to change all my code prior to this section?

Comment: When I run your updated statement, only 2,100,26/09/2017 is returned, so the detailsID for 3 isn't selected AND the record for detailsID 2 that is selected, isn't the most recent record (most recent would be the bottom one, although the dates are the same)

Comment: @DorothyChen ^^^

Comment: @LottieT what is the data type for the `date` column? if it is a datetime data type then there is no problem, if it is string or nvarchar then it won't work.

Comment: @LottieT - You're welcome anytime, have a nice day :D

Comment: @DorothyChen I have changed the formatting! I can select the two records as you have done above, however if two dates are the same, I would like the more recelty added record (nearer bottom) ? With your most recent fiddle, with id 2, you have selected score 100, although 0 and 45 respectively have the same date. Why has it chosen 100? I would like it to choose the most recent so in this case, 45.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MYCTE AS 
 (
  SELECT DetailsId, [Topic 1 Score], ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Partition BY            DetailsID ORDER BY DATE DESC) Num
  FROM Scores
)
SELECT * FROM MYCTE WHERE num = 1
GO
```

Comment: This isn't (quite) MySQL syntax